# Making a Visual Studio-alike interface : Document tabs

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I'm currently making an dynamic interface using the latest version of DevExpress. I finished making the `DockManager` with multiple `DockPanel` in it but there's only one problem.

If you look on screenshot #1 you'll notice that in the center of Visual Studio, there's no `DockPanel` (screenshot #2) container for those document tabs. Also, those document tabs CAN'T dock inside side panels, but side panels CAN dock inside document panels (see screenshot #3)

That is what I'm trying to do. You can see how far I am right now on screenshot #4.

So here's a summary of my questions :

1) How could I make some kind of main document panels that are filling the blank space between my side `DockPanel`?

**FOUND!** Using DevX's DocumentManager as the MDI.

2) How could I make those panel undockable inside side `DockPanel` but make the opposite possible?

**FOUND!** Using DevX's DocumentManager as the MDI.

3) How to make the panels "maximizable" like this (see screenshot #5) when outside the main window ?

4) By default, the tabs are located at the bottom of a stack of DockPanel, but I would like them to be ALWAYS located at the top, would it be possible?

**FOUND!** Using DevX's DocumentManager as the MDI.

Thank you very much!

---

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: Screenshot #1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: Screenshot #2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: Screenshot #3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: Screenshot #4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: Screenshot #5]

Comment: I don't see the difference.  If you expect DevExpress to work exactly like Visual Studio, well that is unlikely to happen, it will work very similar.  The rest of your question can simply be answered by, code the ability and add the button to the control, thats how DevExpress did it.

Comment: Isn't Visual Studio done with DevExpress, DevX are the tools used to build MS Office and such if I'm not mistaken. There shouldn't be any custom code to put over DevX to have that working as VS does...

Comment: Er, no. Microsoft has nothing to do with DevExpress, and Office *certainly* isn't written with DevExpress components. Office is not even written in .NET.

Comment: What version of DevExpress controls are you using? There is the WinForms Project Wizard for C#.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this article on CodeProject [Visual Studio IDE like Dock Container](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/toolbars/VS_IDE_Dock_Container.aspx).

It implements docking windows and a tabbed window layout.

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for, I'd like to use DevX as much as possible. But THANKS for this link, I'll surely use that in my personal projects!!!